# SQL Server 'To XML' Tag Name

Tags: sql-server, xml, csv

I have the following code in the select block of my query which picks out rows from a table and outputs them in XML:

```
select ...
       ...
,substring(
        (
            Select RC_1.Master_Code  AS [TopographyTDR]
            From apex.Histo_Result_Coding as RC_1
            Where RC_1.Histo_Report = Histo_Result_Coding.Histo_Report
            ORDER BY RC_1.Histo_report
            For XML auto
        ), 1, 1000) [TDRCodes]
       ...
```

and this gives an output similar to that shown below:

```
<RC_1 TopographyTDR="T77100"/><RC_1 TopographyTDR="T77100"/>
<RC_1 TopographyTDR="T01000"/><RC_1 TopographyTDR="T01000"/>
<RC_1 TopographyTDR="EGFR "/> <RC_1 TopographyTDR="GHER2"/>
<RC_1 TopographyTDR="T04020"/><RC_1 TopographyTDR="T04020"/>
<RC_1 TopographyTDR="T77100"/><RC_1 TopographyTDR="T77100"/>
```

This is the correct data, but I need the tag to be 'TopographyTDR' without the RC_1. i.e. the data should look like:

```
 <TopographyTDR="T77100"/><TopographyTDR="T77100"/>
 <TopographyTDR="T01000"/><TopographyTDR="T01000"/>
 <TopographyTDR="EGFR "/> <TopographyTDR="GHER2"/>
 <TopographyTDR="T04020"/><TopographyTDR="T04020"/>
 <TopographyTDR="T77100"/><TopographyTDR="T77100"/>
```

Is there a simple way to do this? i.e. to avoid having the table name appear in the XML tag text?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [for xml path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb510462(v=SQL.120).aspx) instead of `for xml auto` and specify tag names explicitly.

Something like:

```
Select RC_1.Master_Code  AS 'TopographyTDR'
From apex.Histo_Result_Coding as RC_1
Where RC_1.Histo_Report = Histo_Result_Coding.Histo_Report
ORDER BY RC_1.Histo_report
for XML path('')
```

**Update:**

Looking at your desired output more precisely - it doesn't looks like valid xml.

Despite on missing root node (it could be omitted for simplicity, I suppose), this format has fundamental problem: tag like `<TopographyTDR="T77100"/>` in fact **doesn't has tag name** but only has attribute `TopographyTDR` having value `T77100`. Are you sure you want such a pseudo-xml data?

Comment: Haven't you looked at the other answers more precisely :-)   Never mind... And no, the root node may not be omitted for simplicity. If there are many items there has to be a root node for validity!

Comment: By "omitted for simplicity" I mean "omitted in the question", not "in the real xml data".

Answer (score 1):

Your desired format is not allowed. An XML node must have a tag name and a content or attributes. And you'll need a root...

You must use `PATH` instead of `AUTO`. Look at this:

```
select top 3 name 
from sys.objects 
for xml path(''),ROOT('root');

select top 3 name AS [@attrib] 
from sys.objects 
for xml path('item'),ROOT('root')
```